# I am working on a ML model to predict promotion and this block is raising an error ie 'TypeError: None is not an estimator instance.'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, typeerror, decision-tree

```
prediction = RFECV.predict(np.array([[2, #department code
                                      3, #masters degree
                                      1, #male
                                      1, #1 training
                                      30, #30 years old
                                      5, #previous year rating
                                      10, #length of service
                                      1, #KPIs met >80%
                                      1, #awards won
                                      95, #avg training score
                                      7, #sum of metric 
                                      700 #total score
                                     ]]))

print("Whether the Employee should get a Promotion : 1-> Promotion, and 0-> No Promotion :", prediction)
```

I am working on a ML model to predict promotion and was at the finalization part.
This block is raising an error ie

```
'TypeError: None is not an estimator instance.'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you this time).

Comment: Where do your `RFECV` comes from ?

Comment: I imported it earlier from sklearn.feature_selection

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use comments in the middle of an array
Use this instead

```
prediction = RFECV.predict(np.array([[2,
                                      3,
                                      1,
                                      1,
                                      30,
                                      5,
                                      10,
                                      1,
                                      1,
                                      95,
                                      7,
                                      700
                                     ]]))
```

Comment: No sir, that's not the way.